# Hiding something so that it cannot be viewed using inspect in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to make a small website in which if the user guesses the right code they win. What I am doing is this:

```
<script>
    function z() {
        var b = document.getElementById('idea');
        var a = document.getElementById("test");
        if (a.value == "code") {
            document.getElementById('err').style.color="green"
            document.getElementById('err').innerHTML= 'Code Correct';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('err').style.color="red"
            document.getElementById('err').innerHTML= 'Referral Code';
        }
    }
</script>
```

But, if a user opens the 'inspect' window, they can see the code beforehand in the `script` tag. Is there any way that this can be prevented?

Also, I tried it by sending data from Django in an input field value like this:
`<input type="hidden" id="b" value="{{code}}">` and then in the `script` tag I did `if (a.value == b.value)` but then, also in the input tag, one can see the value on inspecting.

Comment: It has to be handled server-side, nothing can be 100% hidden on the frontend

Comment: That is what my question is . HOW?

Comment: There are lots of ways, depends on your use case. From what you've posted, make a request from the frontend with the users input and do the `if` check on the backend to see if it's correct

Comment: You could try javascript obfuscation.  This rewrites your code in such a way that it becomes difficult, or impossible, for a user to understand.  Have a look at [link](https://obfuscator.io) for an example of this.

Comment: If you don't want an extra round trip to the server, you could try sending a cryptographic hash (e.g. bcrypt) and comparing against the hashed value on the front end.

Comment: i don't get why the downvotes for the question. it's a completely valid question for a person who has little to no experience with web programming.

Answer (score 2):

As @Daniel_Knights and @ATD noted, you have two options to hide information in a website: move the code to back end or use obfuscation.

What obfuscation usually does is to automatically scan and analyse your code and rewrite it in such a way that is not readable for a human but without changing what the code does. This is achieved by renaming JavaScript variables, functions, parameters and classes to short illegible names like "a", "a1", "_2", but more complex obfuscators are also capable of rearranging code in order to make it more obscure. Obfuscation is good when you need to protect your code and you want to make it hard for your intellectual work to be stolen. Obfuscation is a reversible process, though, as it is deterministic, meaning that theoretically everybody with enough motivation and technical skills could reverse engineer the code and eventually figure it out.

The viable solution for you is to add a programmable server to your web site. I would recommend https://nodejs.org/en/, as it is a modern, popular, well documented and stable web server that can run both on linux and windows.

Your web site currently seems to be a simple html page with some JavaScript in it. The JavaScript code loads and executes solely in the visitor's web browser, it's all copied to the user's computer and hence it's fully accessible for inspection and reverse engineering. A programmable web server like NodeJS runs on a remote computer under your control and all code running on this server is isolated from the it's users, cannot be accessed from outside the computer and provides you with a location to hold your sensitive data like the wining ticket number.

I would suggest that you read this article and maybe do further research before you continue:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model